# Validating Form on Submit button

Tags: javascript, html

All,

I am creating a basic form that just registers an "account" and that is it. I am beginning to work through my validation. It works on validating an empty field for all of the boxes but when It went to put in the alert to say that the form has been submitted on the submit click it does not work. It is not throwing any errors so it is something logically possibly where I placed it but I have moved it inside and outside the validateform fuction but it will not send the alert.

- Note on the first if statement you will see where I start to add the extra constraints of the validation for the length of the username. I have working one bit at at time so it's not complete and tested. I just wanted to make sure that the alert pops up that it has been submitted before moving forward.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">

  //Here will go all the functions and codes.
  function validateForm(){

  var username = document.forms["registerForm"]["username"];               
  var password = document.forms["registerForm"]["password"];    
  var fName = document.forms["registerForm"]["fName"];  
  var lName =  document.forms["registerForm"]["lName"];  
  var dob = document.forms["registerForm"]["dob"];  
  var email = document.forms["registerForm"]["email"];
  var number = document.forms["registerForm"]["number"];

  if((username.value == "") && (username.value >= 8)){
  window.alert("Please enter your username or is 8 characters");

  return false;
  }

  if(password.value == ""){
  window.alert("Please enter your password");

  return false;
  }

  if(fName.value == ""){
  window.alert("Please enter your first name");

  return false;
  }

  if(lName.value == ""){
  window.alert("Please enter your last name");

  return false;
  }

  if(dob.value == ""){
  window.alert("Please enter your Date Of Birth");

  return false;
  }

  if(email.value == ""){
  window.alert("Please enter your E-Mail");

  return false;
  }

  if(number.value == ""){
  window.alert("Please enter your phone number");

  return false;
  }

  alert("Your information as been submitted!");
  } 





  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Form:</h2>
  All boxes are to be filled out except for phone
  <form name="registerForm">

  <h3>Username (At least 8 characters)</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "">
  <P>

  <h3>Password (At least 8 characters)</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "password" value = "">
  <P>

  <h3>First Name</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "fName" value = "">
  <P>

  <h3>Last Name</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "lName" value = "">
  <P>

  <h3>Date Of Birth (In MM/DD/YYYY format)</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "dob" value = "">
  <P>

  <h3>Email</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "email" value = "">
  <P>

  <h3>Phone Number (optional must be in XXX-XXX-XXXX format)</h3>
  <input type = "text" name = "number" value = "">
  <P>


  <input type = "button" value = "Register" onClick = "validateForm()">

  <input type="reset">
  <p>

  </form>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: now what to u want to do u have have alert if the username is not given or if the length is less than 8 characters and u want to have alert on submitting the form 'm right ?

Comment: at the moment I am not working on the length just yet. The alert below is not running. So if ran right now if you have everything filled out (regardless of formatting or length at this time) I should receive that the form has been submitting but it does not run.  alert("Your information as been submitted!");

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the length of the username use `username.value.length`

```
if ((username.value == "") && (username.value.length <= 8)) {
        window.alert("Please enter your username or is 8 characters");
        return false;
      }
```

I hope this is what u r expecting

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function validateForm() {

      var username = document.forms["registerForm"]["username"];
      var password = document.forms["registerForm"]["password"];
      var fName = document.forms["registerForm"]["fName"];
      var lName = document.forms["registerForm"]["lName"];
      var dob = document.forms["registerForm"]["dob"];
      var email = document.forms["registerForm"]["email"];
      var number = document.forms["registerForm"]["number"];
      if ((username.value == "") && (username.value.length <= 8)) {
        window.alert("Please enter your username or is 8 characters");
        return false;
      }
      if (password.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your password");
        return false;
      }
      if (fName.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your first name");
        return false;
      }
      if (lName.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your last name");
        return false;
      }
      if (dob.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your Date Of Birth");
        return false;
      }
      if (email.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your E-Mail");
        return false;
      }
      if (number.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your phone number");
        return false;
      }
      alert("Your information as been submitted!");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Form:</h2>
  All boxes are to be filled out except for phone
  <form name="registerForm">
    <h3>Username (At least 8 characters)</h3>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    <P>
      <h3>Password (At least 8 characters)</h3>
      <input type="text" name="password" value="">
      <P>

        <h3>First Name</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fName" value="">
        <P>
          <h3>Last Name</h3>
          <input type="text" name="lName" value="">
          <P>
            <h3>Date Of Birth (In MM/DD/YYYY format)</h3>
            <input type="text" name="dob" value="">
            <P>
              <h3>Email</h3>
              <input type="text" name="email" value="">
              <P>
                <h3>Phone Number (optional must be in XXX-XXX-XXXX format)</h3>
                <input type="text" name="number" value="">
                <P>
                  <input type="button" value="Register" onClick="validateForm()">
                  <input type="reset">
                  <p>
  </form>

</html>
```

Comment: That is perfect! I wonder where i went wrong that it wasn't popped up that it was submitted. Who knows I probably needed rest after looking at it for hours.